# Is the domain of $y(x) = (5^{2/3} - x^{2/3})^{3/2}$ $[-5, 5]$ and if so why doesn't Maple plot the entire domain?

Tags: calculus, maple

On the platform MIT OCW, there is a course 18.01SC, single-variable calculus. There is a problem set with the following problem:

> Find the area of the astroid $x^{2/3} +y^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$ revolved
> around the x-axis.

To solve this, we form an integral of arc length revolved around the x-axis: $$\int 2 \pi y \sqrt{1 + (y')^2} dx$$
The issue is in figuring out the interval of the integral.

If I solve the equation for $y$ using $a=5$ and ask Maple to plot it, I get:
[image: Plot of y(x)]

Note that $$y(x) = (5^{2/3} - x^{2/3})^{3/2}$$

so we see that indeed for values of x larger than $|5|$ the value inside the root becomes negative so we are not in real numbers anymore. It makes sense to me that the domain of the function is $[-5,5]$.

**Why doesn't Maple show values of the function for $x \in [-5,0)$?**

Comment: Please show your Maple code.

Comment: f := x -> (-x^(2/3) + 5^(2/3))^(3/2); plot(f)

Comment: Okay, thank you!  I think it is doing the same thing that *Mathematica* is doing, which is when it calculates $x^{2/3}$ for $x<0$, it first takes the cube root, resulting in a complex number, then squares it (another complex number).  Thus the plot is "off the charts".

Comment: Try evaluating $(-3)^{2/3},$ for example.

Comment: if I type in -3^(2/3) and then approximate to five digits I get -2.0801

Comment: Also try  `f := x -> (-abs(x^(2/3))+ 5^(2/3))^(3/2); plot(f)'

Comment: (-3)^(2/3) ${}{}{}$

Comment: (−3)2/3 evaluates to a complex number. The function above with the absolute operator generates the expected result with the [-5,0) portion of the domain included. I am new to Maple, is this type of thing expected or is it a sort of bug?

Comment: There are three cube roots of $(-3)$.  You were expecting a particular one, but by default, if $x<0$, then $x^{1/3} = |x|^{1/3} e^{i\pi/3} \ne  (-x)^{1/3}.$   In this case, you have to tell it which root you want.

Comment: Works well in Geogebra

Answer (score 4):

You could read the Maple Help-pages for topics [root](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=root) (especially 4th and 5th bullet points), and [surd](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=surd).

```
plot((5^(2/3)-surd(x,3)^2)^(3/2), x=-5...5);
```

[image]

An alternative is to try and run your example under the [RealDomain](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=RealDomain) package. Note this difference in behavior:

```
restart;

(-8.0) ^ (2/3);

    -2.000000001 + 3.464101615 I

with(RealDomain):

(-8.0) ^ (2/3);

          4.000000000
```

After loading that package (only needed once per session) you could obtain the same plot as above, ie.

```
restart;
with(RealDomain):
plot((5^(2/3)-x^(2/3))^(3/2), x=-5...5);
```

This happens to handle your given example, but can have issues (that are more difficult to figure out, let alone resolve) with more involved examples. It's not my preferred approach.